# Command Line Nodemon

Tags: express, visual-studio-code, command-line, nodemon

Originally, I was developing my backend for my project, but now I want to start developing the front-end so I put all my documents for my backend into a folder called "server". However, I used to run the application using  `nodemon index.js` but because it is in a folder now, this won't run. I am not sure how to access it and make it run.

The folder structure is below:
Application
|--- Server(folder)
|-- index.js
|-- package.json

In VScode, my terminal is the following

```
name@MacBook-Pro Project-Application--main %
```

Comment: _"this won't run"_. You have to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the command with new path

```
nodemon Server/index.js
```

if you want nodemon to restart if only files change in Server folder,
create a nodemon.json in the same folder as package.json

```
{
  "watch": [
    "Server/"
  ]
}
```